# c# - Improve execution time when generating report

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have a program in visual studio 2010 where I have a function to generate report to crystal report. The query is supplied in one of my stored procedure to retrieve information from my database.

The issue I have when I click generate report, it takes a long time to return the result. I was wondering if anyone has suggestion on how to improve the execution time faster by optimizing the query in the stored procedure ?

Here is a snippet of the stored procedure:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[M_RPT_DailyIssuedVoucher]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
BEGIN
EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[M_RPT_DailyIssuedVoucher]
    @EventCode [varchar](8),
    @LocID [varchar](10),
    @Status [char](2),
    @DtFrom [datetime],
    @DtTo [datetime],
    @IssuedBy [nvarchar](128)
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON


Select SerialNo,
         CardID,
         CardHolder AS [Name],
         CardType,
         EventCode,
         IssueDate, 
         IssueBy,
         ValidFromDate,
         ValidToDate,
         IssueLocationID,
         IssueComputerName,
         ManualIssueReason, 
         [Status],
         Remarks,
         CancelReason
/*      '' CollectedStatus ='' +
            '' CASE''+ 
                '' WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(CollectBy))<>'''''''' THEN ''''Y''''''+
                '' ELSE ''''N''''''+
            '' END'' +
*/
    FROM IssuedVoucher with (nolock)
    WHERE 
(@EventCode = '''' OR (EventCode = @EventCode))
And(@IssuedBy = '''' OR (IssueBy= @IssuedBy))
AND (@LocID = '''' OR (IssueLocationID = @LocID))
AND (@Status = '''' OR (Status = @Status))
AND(@DtFrom IS NULL OR IssueDate >= @DtFrom )
AND (@DtTo IS NULL OR IssueDate <= @DtTo)

 ORDER BY SerialNo, EventCode
```

Here is the query for create table for issuedvoucher :

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[IssuedVoucher]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IssuedVoucher](
    [BatchNo] [decimal](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [SerialNo] [varchar](15) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [ManualIssueReason] [varchar](250) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [IssueLocationId] [varchar](8) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [IssueComputerName] [varchar](25) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [Remarks] [varchar](250) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [CardId] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [CardHolder] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [CardType] [varchar](5) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [EventCode] [varchar](8) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [PromotionBenefitCode] [varchar](8) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [ValidFromDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ValidToDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [VisiblePoint] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [HiddenPoint] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [LoyaltyPoint] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [NNECash] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [Status] [char](2) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [PrintStatus] [char](2) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [IssueDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [IssueBy] [nvarchar](128) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [CollectDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [CollectBY] [nvarchar](128) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [CollectLocationId] [varchar](10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [CancelReason] [varchar](250) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [LastChangeBy] [nvarchar](128) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [LastChangeDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [RecordVersion] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [AllotmentID] [decimal](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [GuestType] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [CompanyID] [bigint] NULL,
    [DepartmentID] [smallint] NULL,
    [IDIssuedCountry] [nvarchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [EVoucherBatchNo] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [EVoucherGuestNo] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [EVoucherSerialNo] [varchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [Barcode] [varchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [Monetary] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Discount] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [ConsiderationValue] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [FaceValue] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [IntercoRate] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [SAPCostCentre] [varchar](10) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [SAPIONumber] [varchar](25) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [IsGift] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [PrintCount] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TaxInvoiceID] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [IdentificationNumber] [varchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [IdentificationType] [varchar](5) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [CRMEntitlementMasterID] [nvarchar](20) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [DeductPointType] [smallint] NULL,
    [DeductCreditType] [smallint] NULL,
    [AwardPointType] [smallint] NULL,
    [AwardCreditType] [smallint] NULL,
    [AwardCreditValue] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [deductPointvalue] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [deductCreditvalue] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [AwardPointvalue] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_IssuedVoucher2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SerialNo] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = ON, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
END
GO
/****** Object:  Index [_dta_index_IssuedVoucher_18_1736445310__K1]    Script Date: 04/12/2017 3:39:19 PM ******/
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[IssuedVoucher]') AND name = N'_dta_index_IssuedVoucher_18_1736445310__K1')
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [_dta_index_IssuedVoucher_18_1736445310__K1] ON [dbo].[IssuedVoucher]
(
    [BatchNo] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = ON, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

/****** Object:  Index [_dta_index_IssuedVoucher_18_1736445310__K2_K10_7_25_55]    Script Date: 04/12/2017 3:39:19 PM ******/
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[IssuedVoucher]') AND name = N'_dta_index_IssuedVoucher_18_1736445310__K2_K10_7_25_55')
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [_dta_index_IssuedVoucher_18_1736445310__K2_K10_7_25_55] ON [dbo].[IssuedVoucher]
(
    [SerialNo] ASC,
    [EventCode] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [CardId],
    [CancelReason],
    [IdentificationNumber]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = ON, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

/****** Object:  Index [idx_CardID]    Script Date: 04/12/2017 3:39:19 PM ******/
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[IssuedVoucher]') AND name = N'idx_CardID')
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_CardID] ON [dbo].[IssuedVoucher]
(
    [BatchNo] ASC,
    [CardId] ASC,
    [Status] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = ON, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

/****** Object:  Index [IX_IssuedVoucher_1]    Script Date: 04/12/2017 3:39:19 PM ******/
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[IssuedVoucher]') AND name = N'IX_IssuedVoucher_1')
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_IssuedVoucher_1] ON [dbo].[IssuedVoucher]
(
    [CardId] ASC,
    [CardType] ASC,
    [EventCode] ASC,
    [PromotionBenefitCode] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = ON, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

/****** Object:  Index [RecordVoucher]    Script Date: 04/12/2017 3:39:19 PM ******/
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[IssuedVoucher]') AND name = N'RecordVoucher')
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [RecordVoucher] ON [dbo].[IssuedVoucher]
(
    [EVoucherSerialNo] ASC,
    [Barcode] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: which line are you referring to?

Comment: EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[M_RPT_DailyIssuedVoucher]

Comment: It's has been there all the time so I can exec the sp when i generate the report?

Comment: isn't the issue performance lies with the stored proc?

Comment: Have you checked the Execution plan? Index fragmentation?

Comment: Yes everything checks out.

Comment: You may want to consider building up the SQL in `nvarchar` and then execute it using `sp_executesql`. The WHERE should start as `1 == 1` and then concatenate each of the other criteria **only if needed** (e.g. if `EventCode` is **not** blank). Some people will think this opens you up to SQL injection. This is not true if you do it like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql#arguments .

Comment: SQL server 2017 but my application is running in visual studio 2010.

Comment: about 2mins give or take

Comment: The generate report displays in crystal report viewer based on the date filtered. It only returns 3-4 rows . The reason is also because the Issued Voucher table is a huge table with millions of records so you can imagine the execution time.

Comment: see the edited post for the index

Comment: So, what is the execution plan after all? I don't see how any of those indexes might help a lot with execution of this procedure.

Comment: Only the BatchNo in the first index helps with the excution plan.

Comment: You need to add an index on `EventCode` and a separate index on `IssueDate`.

Comment: As for stored proc, leave it as it is?

Comment: That;s a good suggestion anyway, perhaps you could post it as answer as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, the WHERE operator might be the problem. I had a similar issue, not with a reporting engine, but rather with accessing information from a database.
Imo, the IS NULL is costing performance. I might be wrong though, since I am not a crack at database.
I solved my issue with rather excluding the IS NULL statements. After I got my collection of data, I generated a new collection in C# which includes such statements.

Comment: So what do you think will help?

Comment: Is it correct that the IssueDate is a nullable DateTime? When I am not mistaken, he will check all entries, because of IS NULL. You should consider splitting up the query imo. Getting all valid IssueDates, then all null IssueDates and merge them into one collection.

Comment: Btw, how do you access the this stored procedure in your c# context? entity framework?

Comment: I call the stored proc in my c# code with command.parameters.addwithvalue ( parameter name in stored proc)

Comment: Okay, since the EF can lead to performance issues. Did you consider to use an INDEX on your tables? @mjwills had a good idea.

Comment: Yes i did have indexes created in issuedvoucher table. But i didn't include it in the post because it's too tedious.

Comment: The thing is the WHERE clause is inevitable and must be included in the proc.

Comment: be carefull with the AddWithValue statement in c#. Read this https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: I was using this :  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventCode",strEvCode );

Comment: What about using this? paramFields.Add("EventCode", (strEvCode == "" ? "ALL" : strEvCode));

Comment: Yes i did, you want me to change data type to nvarchar?

Answer (score 0):

First of all,  why you alter proc every time is not understandable to me ?

you may simply call proc from your code and put only Select onward in dynamic Sql.

you can modify your inner select query in this manner.If your table is well index then it may take advantage of index .

```
             declare @EventCode [varchar](8)
   declare @LocID [varchar](10)
   declare @Status [char](2)
   declare @DtFrom [datetime]
   declare @DtTo [datetime]
   declare @IssuedBy [nvarchar](128)
   declare @SqlCondtion nvarchar(max)=''

   DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);  
    SET @ParmDefinition = N'@EventCode1 [varchar](8) 
                            , @LocID1 [varchar](10) 
                            , @Status1 [char](2)
                            , @DtFrom1 [datetime] 
                            ,@DtTo1 [datetime]
                            ,@IssuedBy1 [nvarchar](128)';  

declare @Sql nvarchar(max)=N'Select SerialNo,
         CardID,
         CardHolder AS [Name],
         CardType,
         EventCode,
         IssueDate, 
         IssueBy,
         ValidFromDate,
         ValidToDate,
         IssueLocationID,
         IssueComputerName,
         ManualIssueReason, 
         [Status],
         Remarks,
         CancelReason
    FROM IssuedVoucher with (nolock)
    WHERE 1=1 ' 

if(@EventCode is not null) 
set @SqlCondtion=@SqlCondtion+CHAR(10)+ 'and EventCode = @EventCode1 '

if(@IssuedBy is not null)
set @SqlCondtion=@SqlCondtion+CHAR(10)+ 'and IssueBy = @IssuedBy1 '


if(@LocID is not null  )
set @SqlCondtion=@SqlCondtion+CHAR(10)+ 'and IssueLocationID = @LocID1 '

if(@Status is not null )
set @SqlCondtion=@SqlCondtion+CHAR(10)+ 'and [Status] = @Status1 '

if(@DtFrom is not null )
set @SqlCondtion=@SqlCondtion+CHAR(10)+ 'and [IssueDate] >= @DtFrom1 '

if(@DtTo is not null )
set @SqlCondtion=@SqlCondtion+CHAR(10)+ 'and [IssueDate] <= @DtTo1 '

set @Sql=@Sql+CHAR(10)+@SqlCondtion

print @Sql
EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql, @ParmDefinition, @EventCode1 = @EventCode, @IssuedBy1=@IssuedBy ,@LocID1=@LocID
                                            ,@Status1=@Status,@DtFrom1=@DtFrom,@DtTo1=@DtTo;
```

you can further modify this script suiting you requirement or fix bug.print should be commented after debug.

Comment: @mjwills,stop downvoting before reading the whole answer or understanding it.where I am using Exec (@Sql) in my script.where i am forbidding user to use sp_executesql. Since User is already using sp_executesql and I hv given only part of solution.Hv you really understood my answer ?

Comment: yup your comment are valuable.please wait for my correction, I am coming with Bob.

Comment: Thanks for pointing error.I hv done this lot of time.don't know why I miss so many thing.may be i was trying to give rough idea here.

Comment: @mjwills ,are you gone ?check my answer and last 2 comments.

Comment: @mjwills,so you think my logic will not help above user ?it will not improve performance ?

Comment: I removed the downvote. It is definitely vastly improved over the original code.

Comment: @mjwills, No i wanted to know your opinion that  my script will help above user who ask question or not.